# CAS Single Signout not working

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas

I have done the below changes to enable single signout:

```
1. Add org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter as the first filter in filter chain.
2. Include org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener in web.xml
```

But client sessions are not invalidated. Do you know why?

This is my server log which indicates that the server is sending logout requests to both the clients:

```
181 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.TGCCipherExecutor] - <Successfully decoded value. Result in Base64-encoding is [ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUprYVhJaUxDSmxibU1pT2lKQk1USTRRMEpETFVoVE1qVTJJbjAuLjkzeTVhNFJkc2N0WTlPdXhWOVlMWHcuaVZVSUlfdWpwMlo2UmJXZnFQR05BUXd2cW1lS3RuRlljbGNfZlFGclZSWGN1Y05qVXp2UC1LTW5OT3JfYUNTbzc1SWc5TDg4YS1lTlBsSlQ2MnUzUi1ILVplLW1iQTFFQ0I4RDY1am51WHR6R3h3RzA2b0tXS3FyQmxhNFh3amtkNEpqQzhneEFONlJ1Sk1aZEY3ZGg1cGVnSGo5ZklIdVVETjM5TC1WVk5VeTgzTXpORFlqYzJJMjZUMTJ5dGIwVTlpbXFTQ056dTVybFZDaW9XNnBqWC14VU1mQ01RSTd4MTVCOEhrWmxFZ2xUX2gzTnpnSjgtX3ZtczUweFBFZmJ2UjF1eHNCX0FTRWdMd2gwSTFCZlEub2JzcGFOVk1CcWNxWk1CZWtCeGJIQQ==]>
181 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.util.TGCCipherExecutor] - <Decrypting value...>
182 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.DefaultCasCookieValueManager] - <Decoded cookie value is [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1@Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36]>
183 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Removing ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org] from registry...>
183 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org]>
183 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org] found in registry.>
184 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Ticket found. Processing logout requests and then deleting the ticket...>
185 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.SamlCompliantLogoutMessageCreator] - <Generated logout message: [<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-5-XbgucCuIidiGsh1TjFeEcwsWKSUqIWk7oCw" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-08-11T13:00:17Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-6-JkoiXK3anY5RQKZwgJYB-cas01.example.org</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>]>
185 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Sending logout request for: [https://localhost:8443/test/newviews/home.xhtml]>
187 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Prepared logout message to send is [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl$LogoutHttpMessage@6dfc3c30[url=https://localhost:8443/test/newviews/home.xhtml,message=<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-5-XbgucCuIidiGsh1TjFeEcwsWKSUqIWk7oCw" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-08-11T13:00:17Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-6-JkoiXK3anY5RQKZwgJYB-cas01.example.org</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>,asynchronous=true,contentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded]]>
188 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Captured logout request [org.jasig.cas.logout.DefaultLogoutRequest@30c9f96b[ticketId=ST-6-JkoiXK3anY5RQKZwgJYB-cas01.example.org,service=https://localhost:8443/test/newviews/home.xhtml,status=SUCCESS]]>
189 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Connecting socket to localhost/127.0.0.1:8443 with timeout 5000>
191 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.SamlCompliantLogoutMessageCreator] - <Generated logout message: [<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-6-DgpO6cQ1ySIrFlAKjmLctLfSdVgkqUoQOI9" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-08-11T13:00:17Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-7-RhZCrItuoTVLcaJv2rdC-cas01.example.org</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>]>
191 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]>
191 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]>
191 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Starting handshake>
191 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Sending logout request for: [https://localhost:7443/cas-sample/secure/index.jsp]>
191 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Prepared logout message to send is [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl$LogoutHttpMessage@68a12efb[url=https://localhost:7443/cas-sample/secure/index.jsp,message=<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="LR-6-DgpO6cQ1ySIrFlAKjmLctLfSdVgkqUoQOI9" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2016-08-11T13:00:17Z"><saml:NameID xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">@NOT_USED@</saml:NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>ST-7-RhZCrItuoTVLcaJv2rdC-cas01.example.org</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>,asynchronous=true,contentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded]]>
193 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Captured logout request [org.jasig.cas.logout.DefaultLogoutRequest@7a9049cf[ticketId=ST-7-RhZCrItuoTVLcaJv2rdC-cas01.example.org,service=https://localhost:7443/cas-sample/secure/index.jsp,status=SUCCESS]]>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Connecting socket to localhost/127.0.0.1:7443 with timeout 5000>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org]>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Secure session established>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < peer principal: CN=localhost, OU=IT, O=xxxx, L=xxxx, ST=xxxx, C=xxxx>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < issuer principal: CN=localhost, OU=IT, O=xxxx, L=xxxx, ST=xxxx, C=xxxx>
194 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org] found in registry.>
195 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Removing children of ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org] from the registry.>
195 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Removing ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org] from the registry.>
196 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Publishing org.jasig.cas.support.events.CasTicketGrantingTicketDestroyedEvent@1a5ff277[ticketGrantingTicket=TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org]>
197 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]>
197 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.AssertionAsReturnValuePrincipalResolver] - <Trying to see if target's return value is instance of [Assertion]...>
197 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]>
197 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Starting handshake>
197 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.AssertionAsReturnValuePrincipalResolver] - <Resolving principal from the delegate principal resolver: [org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.TicketOrCredentialPrincipalResolver@247e35d8]...>
198 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.TicketOrCredentialPrincipalResolver] - <Resolving argument [String] for audit>
198 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry] - <Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org]>
199 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org] by type [Ticket] cannot be found in the ticket registry.>
202 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.TicketOrCredentialPrincipalResolver] - <Could not locate ticket [TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org] in the registry>
202 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.AssertionAsReturnValuePrincipalResolver] - <Meaningful principal id could not be resolved by [org.jasig.cas.audit.spi.AssertionAsReturnValuePrincipalResolver@6e9c9d27]. Returning [audit:unknown]...>
203 INFO [org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | =============================================================
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | WHO: audit:unknown
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | WHAT: TGT-**********************************************xO0zbG1hVN-cas01.example.org
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_DESTROYED
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | APPLICATION: CAS
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | WHEN: Thu Aug 11 13:00:17 EDT 2016
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | SERVER IP ADDRESS: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | =============================================================
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/08/11 13:00:17 | >
203 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.support.TGCCookieRetrievingCookieGenerator] - <Removed cookie with name [TGC]>
203 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.web.WarningCookieRetrievingCookieGenerator] - <Removed cookie with name [CASPRIVACY]>
206 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.services.web.RegisteredServiceThemeBasedViewResolver] - <View resolved: /WEB-INF/view/jsp/default/ui/casLogoutView.jsp>
210 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - <Secure session established>
210 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2>
210 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256>
210 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < peer principal: CN=localhost, OU=IT, O=xxxx, L=xxxx, ST=xxxx, C=xxxx>
210 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.FileTrustStoreSslSocketFactory] - < issuer principal: CN=localhost, OU=IT, O=xxxx, L=xxxx, ST=xxxx, C=xxxx>
```

During my further analysis, I changed SLO callbacks to synchronous.

```
slo.callbacks.asynchronous=false
```

Now I get `WARN [org.jasig.cas.logout.LogoutManagerImpl] - <Logout message not sent to [https://localhost:8443/test/newviews/home.xhtml]; Continuing processing...>`

So that means the logout messages were not sent to clients. I also noticed that there are no org.jasig.cas.util.SimpleHttpClient entries in my logs. I think this is the issue. Any suggestions to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling the logs as the "trace" level. That should give you more details on what is happening behind the scenes.